# How build clang-tools? "make clang-tools" does nothing

Tags: clang, llvm

I succesfully checked-out llvm (v12) project and built llvm+clang invoking:

```
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" ../llvm
make check-all
```

After this operation empty `clang-tools` directory appeared. After calling `make clang` it remains empty. When I call `make clang-tools` it does nothing - there is a target with this name because there is no error info about missing target but the command doesn't do nor print anything. On the other hand, when I try `make clang-tools-extra` it complains that there is no such project despite the fact that I configured it with cmake. So I'm also unable to build clang-tools-extra.

What am I doing wrong?

update:
There is no `CMakeFiles` directory in llvm/clang/tools which is - I think - unexpected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the list of targets in the output of `ninja help` or `make help` or `xcodebuild -list` or any other generator.

A project's external name can very well be different from the internal target name.

If you want to build everything, just set the install prefix:

`cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" ../llvm -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../my_install`

and run `make install`

It will do the right thing.

Comment: True, I think I messed something up when I was trying to call cmake for clang-tools only hoping that I don't need all the rest. It broke the whole build system.

Comment: @ardabro if you just want to cut on compile times, set `-DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ` though i didn't test the reduction in compile times.. see more options at  https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html